# Why is "this" undefined in classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to understand why "this" can be undefined in classes sometimes, and how to fix it. I have read other answers on this but I guess what I'm asking is a solution. I read a lot of open source code because it helps me learn. Every time I see a class, the code just uses this all the way through. Whenever I try to make a class and call this in a callback function, it is undefined. I have used var that = this as a solution but it's causing some issues and I figure this is something I should have figured out a while ago.

Here's an example

```
class myClass {
     constructor(ping) {
        this.run()
        this.ping = ping
     }

     run() {
        console.log(this.ping)
        //This is defined here
        request({
           url: 'https://test.com',
           method: 'get'
           },
           function (err, res, body) {
             this.ran(body)
            //"ran" is not a function
        })
     }

     ran(body) {
        console.log(body)
     }
 }
```

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Use an arrow function to get lexically scoped `this`.

Comment: `this` within functions that are not methods of a class or Constructor or Object refers to the global Object.

Comment: Change `function (err, res, body) {` to `(err, res, body) => {` (ie. use arrow function) to resolve the issue.

Comment: @JJ. and elclanrs too...thank you so much!